# How to resolve generic repository and use it in a single variable?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, repository

I'm trying to built some generic code for tables with the same columns but i have a problem figuring out how to use a generic "resolver" in order to use only one variable.

I tried to use `dynamic` without success and i'm out of ideas.

`Entity1`, `Entity2` and `Entity3` have exactly the same fields (automatically generated from Entity Framework) but there are different tables. Is possible to use only one variable to get the results?

```
var repository1 = new RepositoryBase<Entity1>();
var repository2 = new RepositoryBase<Entity2>();
var repository3 = new RepositoryBase<Entity3>();

Enum RepositoryTypes
{
    Repo1 = 0,
    Repo2 = 1,
    Repo3 = 2
}

//Method Definition: RepositoryResolver(RepositoryTypes repoTypes);
var repository = RepositoryResolver(RepositoryTypes.Repo1); //Example. The RepositoryResolver should return one of the 3 RepositoryBase<EntityX>

var results = repository.Get(record => record.Name.Contains("fist name")).ToList();

foreach(var person in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}, Last Name: {1}", person.Name, person.LastName);
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is an example of the Entities:

```
Entity1 - Belongs to DataBase1
public string Name;
public string LastName;
public string Age;

Entity2 - Belongs to DataBase2
public string Name;
public string LastName;
public string Age;

Entity3 - Belongs to DataBase3
public string Name;
public string LastName;
public string Age;
```

Comment: The entities have the same columns, They share the same table also?

Comment: What do you mean, use one variable? Do you mean one variable instead of `repository1, repository2, repository3`, or do you mean storing the results from all 3 repositories in a single variable?

Comment: I mean to use one variable to query the database `var repository` and then `var results = repository.Get(...)` the `repository` variable will store the entity which i passed to `RepositoryResolver`. Are different tables with the same fields

Comment: It sounds like you need to eliminate two tables and add a column for some sort of TypeId to the remaining table. If all of the columns are the same, then they should all be stored together.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Entity1 (and 2 and 3) declarations, either base them on one abstract class or create and have them implement an interface with said fields. You can then declare the variable through the abstract base class or the interface and voila, you're in the game. Something along the lines of (writing off the top of my head without compiling or intellisense, so there might be typos'n'stuff):

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Name { get; set;}
    string LastName { get; set;}
}

public class Entity1 : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}

public class Entity2 : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
//...and later in your main code...
foreach(IEntity person in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}, Last Name: {1}", person.Name, person.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but unfortunately i don't have access because they are automatically generated from the entity framework... So even if i change them later will change again (if i run the custom tool for T4)

Comment: @CodeArtist Entity framework generates partial classes, so you can create a "partner" partial class definition that implements the interface.